# C++ (C++98) functor with multiple constructors?

Tags: c++, functor

Is it possible to create a functor with multiple constructors? I want to be able to use the functor in various ways, initializing its various members in different ways, all depending upon which constructor is used to set it up initially.

But is there a more elegant solution than the one I propose here using functors with multiple constructors?

This added level of reuse would play very well in the communications wire protocol interpreter I am writing. A particular wire (or a subset of wires) in a communications line can often serve different purposes, depending upon the specific protocol in use. I'd thus like to be able to create a small set of functors that can be adaptable, within reasonable parameters, rather than having to create a large set of very specific functors, each of which has comparatively little adaptability.

The smaller set of highly-adaptable functors would then be used, one at a time, as a parameter to a template function in another class, which function can either read or write data according to the "rules" embodied within the functor parameter used to call that template function.

My aim is to make the code as generic as possible, to allow many different permutations of protocols and sub-protocols to be used with the same basic code.

Comment: The answer is "yes", but I feel like that doesn't answer your real question. What is your real question?

Comment: A functor is essentially a structure with an operator ()()

Comment: There is no such thing as C++99. Perhaps you mean 98?

Comment: "*The smaller set of highly-adaptable functors would then be used, one at a time, as a parameter to a template function in another class, which function can either read or write data according to the "rules" embodied within the functor parameter used to call that template function.*" If that's what you're doing, that's not a *functor* anymore. If you're calling member functions that aren't `operator()`, then you're not treating it as a "functor". It's just a class that has an `operator()` overload among its various other member functions.

Comment: Did you make an attempt? What happened?

Comment: (nicol)->I did mean C++ 98 - sorry about that. I'm not sure I understand why my proposed use of functors as parameters to a template function would violate the purpose of a functor in the 1st place. I propose to init the functor in various ways, pass it to a template, then invoke the functor's methods from inside the template function.    (nwp)->My "real question" is whether functors with multiple constructors will be an elegant solution for my application, or is there a better approach? Thanks for discerning the fact that I didn't actually ask the core question that I should have.

Comment: @user2680840 Perhaps I don't quite understand, but "init in various ways" sounds like something you'd do to an instance (object), while "pass it to a template" sounds like something you do to a type (at compile time). Maybe you could edit the question to *show* what you mean using some code.

Comment: The `std` algorithms are allowed to make multiple copies of the functor(s) passed into them.  This may give you surprising results. eg. quicksort may copy the comparison functor each time it partitions.  In other words you cannot mutate the state of a functor in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. A straight answer is: yes you can, you can even overload the operator().

```
class MyFunctor {
public:
    MyFunctor(int a) : a(a), b(0.0) {}
    MyFunctor(double b) : a(0), b(b) {}

    int operator()(int c) const { return a + c; }
    double operator()(double c) const { return b + c; }
private:
    int a;
    double b;
};

MyFunctor fromInt(2);
MyFunctor fromDouble(2.1);

std::cout << fromInt(3) << std::endl; // Print 5
std::cout << fromInt(3.1) << std::endl; // Print 3.1

std::cout << fromDouble(2) << std::endl; // Print 2
std::cout << fromDouble(2.2) << std::endl; // Print 4.3
```

However, I feel this violate the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). A better solution might be to create several small functors and choose the best one using a factory.

```
class MyFunctorInt {
public:
    MyFunctorInt(int a) : a(a) {}
    int operator()(int c) const { return a + c; }
private:
    int a;
};
class MyFunctorDouble {
public:
    MyFunctorDouble(double b) : b(b) {}
    double operator()(double c) const { return b + c; }
private:
    double b;
};

MyFunctorInt createFunctor(int a)
{ return MyFunctorInt(a); }
MyFunctorDouble createFunctor(double b)
{ return MyFunctorDouble(b); }

template<class Callable, class Real>
void myGenericFunction(const Callable &f, Real a)
{ std::cout << f(a) << std::endl; }

myGenericFunction(createFunctor(2),3); // Print 5
myGenericFunction(createFunctor(2.2),3); // Print 5.2
```

This probably scales better, since if you want to add a new capability to your code, e.g. for strings, you can just create a new file in which there is a new class **MyFunctorString** and a new overload to **createFunctor(std::string)**. You can easily unit-test this new class, and you do not have to worry about interactions between various overloads. For instance, the first time I wrote the code for **MyFunctor**, I forgot to initialise all the members to 0, which lead to undefined results.

Comment: kevin->Your factory approach using several small functors is a very intriguing solution! It's nice because, while I would need to create a collection of functors to cover my needs, the details, and the mechanics of making the choices of which functor(s) to use in each situation, are rather nicely encapsulated, and hidden. It's very maintainable, as you say, and it's powerful. Really very nice! Let me experiment with this, and I'll get back to you with results and questions.